# I have made a range slider for filtering.In ajax part instead of displaying I want to post data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have made a range slider for filtering.In ajax part instead of displaying I want to post data

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#slider").slider({
            range: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 500000,
            step: 1000,
            values: [0, 100],
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                // Get values
                var min = ui.values[0];
                var max = ui.values[1];
                $('#range').text(min + ' - ' + max);
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'insert_ad_details.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        min: min,
                        max: max
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have made a range slider for filtering.In ajax part instead of displaying I want to post data

Comment: can you ask a clear question? Because it seems that you already "post" data.

Comment: Please see [ask] and create a [mcve]. You also need to explain what your question and problem is. repeating the same sentence three times also doesn't help

Comment: In the insert_ad_details page value of min and max is not coming.That is the problem.